# AsyncTask Not working on WallpaperService

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to load some resources in parallel so that they load faster in a wall paper. So I decided to use the AsyncTask in Android wallpaperservice. Below is the code i used. I was shocked to know that the AsyncTask is called synchronously and also that the  onPostExecute is never executed. What is the reason? Is there any alternative?

```
@Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        Log.d("PER", "onCreateEngine");

    new DownloadWebPageTask().doInBackground("test");
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("ASYNC", "DownloadWebPageTask aftersleep outside thread");
    }
    return new CubeEngine();
}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        Log.d("ASYNC", "DownloadWebPageTask start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("ASYNC", "DownloadWebPageTask aftersleep inside thread");
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("ASYNC", "DownloadWebPageTask end");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call `doInBackground` directly. You need to call `execute` like it states in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  That is why your task is executing on the same thread.

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Thank you very much for point it out right... :-)